# Ruby on Rails does not display the right Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

In my patient show view i have a part that refers to a partial

```
<h2>Anamnesen</h2>
<%= render @patient.anamneses %>
```

So i also created an partial in views/anamneses/ called _anamnese.html.erb

```
<p>
<b>Beschreibung:</b>
<%= anamnese.beschreibung %>
</p>
```

Now, my problem is that only **Beschreibung:** can be seen, the                               <%= anamnese.beschreibung %> is somehow blank!  So maybe someones gues what i made wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass variables explicitly by `locals` option for the partials to know it.

In the first template

```
render partial: 'anamneses/anamneses', locals: {anamneses: @patient.anamneses}
```